# Como usar o history no react-router-dom v6

Tags: react, react-router, react-router-dom

alguém sabe como uso o **history** do react-router-dom v6

Eu vi em um projeto aqui um pouco antigo usando a v5 do react-router-dom
Que basicamente se fazia assim

```js
#file history.ts
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
export default createBrowserHistory()

#file app.tsx
import history from './history'
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'

<Router history={history}>
</Router>
```

na v6 do react-router-dom to tentando o seguinte

```js
#file history.ts
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
export default createBrowserHistory()

#file App.tsx
import history from './history'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

<Router history={history}>
</Router>
```

ai recebo o seguinte erro: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls13X.png

Comment: A resposta do amigo **Roberto Athos** está correta, uma pena eu não conseguir dar UpVote nela :( Porém você pode ler a documentação oficial da biblioteca e entender todos esses pontos.
Inclusive essa nova versão do React Router abusa do uso de hooks que são super legais de usar! Você pode ver aqui: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/getting-started/overview

Answer (score -2):

Salve irmão blza? na versão V6 do react-router-dom você terá que fazer da seguinte maneira.

Exemplo:

```
import {Routes, BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

function App(){
   return(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            //aqui você coloca os caminhos que você quiser
            <Route path='/' element={</Home>}/>
            <Route path='/Register' element={</Register>}/>
            <Route path='/Login' element={</Login>}/>
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
)
}
```

Seguindo dessa maneira o seu erro vai sumir, se ainda continuar é só dá um salve aqui.

Comment: não sei se fui muito claro na pergunta, mais o problema não é nem o erro em sí.
Mais como adicionar o history na v6 do react-router-dom
no seu exemplo ai, é um clássico sistema de rota.
no meu caso aqui  no lugar de BrowserROuter coloquei unstable_HistoryRouter as Router.

mais preciso estudar melhor sobre rotas.
Entender melhor.


O que eu reparei é q usando o BrowserRouter ele não gerencia muito bem o historico dos btn de voltar do browser.
Em quanto o unstable_HistoryRouter com a prop history, consegue gerenciar bem.